# Irreducibility in Polynomial Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

(a) How many polynomials of degree $2$ are there in $\Bbb Z_2[x]$? (Justify your answer.) Which ones are irreducible?

(b) Let $P \in\mathbb Z_2[x]$ be a polynomial of degree $4$ that is not irreducible. Show that either $P$ admits a root, or $P$ can be written as the product of two irreducible polynomials of degree $2$.

I know there are $4$ polynomials of degree $2$: $x^2$, $x^2+x$, $x^2+1$ and $x^2+x+1$. However I don't know how to justify this?

Comment: You are not supposed to open alternate accounts to continue asking questions when you have a block on your account. Instead you should edit and improve your previous questions. (apparently you have done this multiple times in the last day)

Answer (score 1):

A polynomial of degree 2 over $\mathbb{Z}_2[x]$ looks like this:

$ax^2+bx+c$ where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}_2$.

So $a,b,c\in\{0,1\}$. Since we have degree 2 we have a=1, and the polynomial takes the form

$x^2+bx+c$. Now there are four possibilities left.

$b=0,1$ and $c=0,1$. (Which you combinate)

After that you only have to figure out which of them are irreducible.

Edit:

When a polynomial of degree 4 is not irreducible, you know that we can write

$ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=(a_1x+b_1)(c_1x^3+d_1x^2+e_1x+f_1)$

In this case it has a root. Which one?
Also this does not mean that the polynomial of degree 3 is irreducible as well.

Or (in the case that it has no root) you can compose it as

$ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=(a_1x^2+b_1x+c_1)(d_1x^2+e_1x+f_1)$

The polynomials are irreducible, because in this case there is no root, which means there is no linear factor.

Comment: Thank you! that makes a lot of sense now. How would I go about part b?

Comment: @HarambeJones I will edit this, I didnt see that you extended your question.

Comment: @HarambeJones You are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The $\Bbb F_2[x]$ polynomials of degree $2$ are precisely those of the form $x^2+bx+c$. Namely, $$p_1(x)=x^2+x+1\;\;\;\;;\;\;\;\;p_2(x)=x^2+x\;\;\;\;;\;\;\;\;\;p_3(x)=x^2+1\;\;\;\;\;;\;\;\;\;\;p_4(x)=x^2$$

but $p_1(x)$ is the only one that is irreducible over $\Bbb F_2$ because it does not have a root in $\Bbb F_2$ ; i.e. $$p_1(\mathbf 1)=p_1(\mathbf 0)=\mathbf 1$$ However, $p_2(x),p_3(x),p_4(x)$ are reducible over $\Bbb F_2$ because each of these polynomials has a root in $\Bbb F_2$ ; i.e. $$p_2(\mathbf 0)=p_3(\mathbf 1)=p_4(\mathbf 0)=\mathbf 0$$
That suffices for (a). Now, assume $f(x)$ is a reducible quartic polynomial in $\Bbb F_2[x]$ with no roots in $\Bbb F_2$ and choose $g(x),h(x)\in\Bbb F_2[x]$ such that $f(x)=g(x)\cdot h(x)$ and $$\deg(g(x)),\deg(h(x))<\deg(f(x))$$ Since $f(x)$ has no $\Bbb F_2$ roots neither of $g(x),h(x)$ are linear or cubic and therefore $\deg(g(x))=\deg(h(x))=2$. Both $g(x),h(x)$ are irreducible over $\Bbb F_2$ or else $f(x)$ has a $\Bbb F_2$ root which is impossible.